# PHP - how to set body into raw in curl

Tags: php, curl

I tried to send data into external rest api call where they are getting data as raw format.

This is my code:

```
$headers = array('Authorization: XXXXXX', 'Content-Type: application/json');
$data = array('name' => 'test', 'age' => 26);
$post['data'] = json_encode($data);
$url = 'My external api url';
$process = curl_init();
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600000);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0 );
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 ' .
  '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.41 Safari/534.7';  // imitate chrome
curl_setopt ($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);

if ($method == 'POST') {
  curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
}
elseif ($method == 'PUT') {
  curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
  curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
}

$response = curl_exec($process);
print_r($response);exit;
```

It gives an empty response. When I tried this in REST API add ons, it gives correct result.

I want to know how to set form body as raw type like form-data, binary & x-www-form-urlencoded?

Please refer the attached image:

[image]

**Answer:**
I tried to pass input in json format. It is working for me.
This is the sample input:

```
{  "data":{ "name": "test", "age": 26 } }
```

Comment: If you pass an array to curl for the POSTFIELDS, then curl will convert that array into www-form. pass in a string, and curl will leave it alone, because it'll assume you've already done whatever was necessary to format that string into whatever the receiver expects.

Comment: I've tried but it still return an empty response

Comment: you SURE it's empty? curl_exec returns boolean false on failure, which print_r will spit out as a zero-length string. do `$response = curl_exec(...); if ($response === false) { die(curl_error($process)); }` instead.

Comment: It return {} only.

Comment: That's not an empty response. that's a response containing an empty object. Since you've provided NO details about what this api is, or how it signals problems, we can't really help you.

Comment: As I told in question details, I've tried this in REST API add ons but it gave valid response only if the body type is raw. Unless it return only {} if the body type is form-data.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

`curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/plain'));`